# In R, how to change `[` semantics to work with a rectangular coordinate system instead of the (default) matrix index system?

Tags: r, subset, r-s4

I would like to redefine the meaning of the subset operator `[` to work with (x, y) coordinates instead of the (i, j) matrix index system. I'd like this to work on matrices (behind the scenes).

I thought initially of creating an S4 class based on the matrix type. And then use the generic function `[` and create a method for it that would do sub-setting with `i`  and `j` swapped. But I realized now I can't change the signature of the generic:

```r
> getGeneric("[")
standardGeneric for "[" defined from package "base"

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) 
standardGeneric("[", .Primitive("["))
<bytecode: 0x55f8eef68ad8>
<environment: 0x55f8eef5f310>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, i, j, drop
Use  showMethods("[")  for currently available ones.
```

So is there a way of doing this? I am thinking of rewriting the definition of `[` but that feels heretic... So, some advice is greatly appreciated!

Here's some pseudo R code that reflects my thoughts on how I could redefine `[`. Do you anticipate trouble ahead if I go forward with this approach?

```r
setClass(
  "plane",
  slots = c(
    type = "character",
    xlen = "integer",
    ylen = "integer",
    boundary = "character",
    lattice = "matrix"
  )
)

`[` <- function(obj, x, y, ..., drop = TRUE) {
  if (is(obj, 'plane')) {

    lattice <- base::`[`(x = obj@lattice, i = y, j = x, ..., drop = FALSE)
    xlen <- length(x)
    ylen <- length(y)
    new_plane <- plane(type = obj@type,
                       xlen = xlen,
                       ylen = ylen,
                       boundary = obj@boundary)
    new_plane@lattice <- lattice

    return(new_plane)
  }
  else
    return(base::`[`(x = obj, i = x, j = y, ..., drop = drop))
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by this example slightly. wouldn't it work if you named the arguments `i` and `j` rather than `x` and `y` and defined a method for `[` with signature `(x="plane")`?